# Why dets file_size doesnot reduce after deleting all the keys

Tags: erlang, dets

I am having problems with the size of dets file.

```
> {ok,D1} = dets:open_file(sample_dets_file, [{type, set},{auto_save,3}]).
{ok,sample_dets_file}

> [dets:insert(D1,{{fid,X},"this is sample data"}) || X <- lists:seq(1,10000)].
> dets:info(D1).

[{type,set},
 {keypos,1},
 {size,10000},
 {file_size,769748},
 {filename,"sample_dets_file"}]

> [dets:delete(D1,{fid,X}) || X <- lists:seq(1,10000)].
> dets:info(D1).

[{type,set},
 {keypos,1},
 {size,0},
 {file_size,770092},
 {filename,"sample_dets_file"}]
```

After insert - `{size,10000}, {file_size,769748}`
After delete-  `{size,0}, {file_size,770092}`.
The file size has not reduced even after table is empty.  However when I execute `delete_all_objects`, file size returns to normal.

```
> dets:delete_all_objects(D1).
> dets:info(D1).

 [{type,set},
 {keypos,1},
 {size,0},
 {file_size,5464},
 {filename,"sample_dets_file"}]
```

I could not understand what additionally i need to do along with delete operation so as to reduce the file_size.
The problem is, since dets file_size is limited to 4gb, even if objects are deleted, I reach the size limit of dets file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dets implementation doesn't try to shrink the file when entries are deleted, except when you do delete_all_objects. To shrink the file manually, you have to create a new temporary dets file, copy all entries to the new file, remove the old file, and rename the temporary file to replace the old.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option how to reduce size of the DETS table (after deletion).

Close this DETS table (dets:close) and open it whit an option {repair, force}.

See the documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.htm

> The only way to defragment a table is to close it and then open it
>   again with the repair option set to force.

When there is no another process which have open this file, the file is compacted.

It works for me.